# Do the Changelings (Founders) appear outside of Star Trek: Deep Space 9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Various Star Trek series and movies have [shape-shifting species](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81673/are-there-any-other-changeling-species-in-the-star-trek-universe-besides-the-fou), but do the Changelings appear in canon outside of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*? If not, has there been any reason stated for this? Major alien species often appear again in later series, but I am not aware of the Changelings appearing after *Deep Space Nine*.

Comment: [Changelings](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81673/are-there-any-other-changeling-species-in-the-star-trek-universe-besides-the-fou), yes. Founders, no.

Comment: The main reason is presumably that one of the pre-conditions of the Dominion surrender was that they'd stay in the Delta Quadrant and mend their ways.

Comment: @Richard The Dominion (and the Great Link) is in the Gamma not the Delta Quadrant...

Comment: @BMWurm - If I was still a moderator, and cared less, I'd edit my comment. Since neither is true, I shall leave it where it is.

Comment: @Richard The convention in naming them was always weird anyway, since it's neither clock- nor counter-clock-wise :P

Comment: Tangential: Salome Jens, the actress that played the Female Changling appears in quite similar makeup in the TNG episode "The Cha se"
http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Chase_(episode) in which her species is shown to be quite literally, the founders of the various civilizations in the galaxy

Comment: @BMWurm - Even more interestingly, the prop treaty ([pictured below](http://i.stack.imgur.com/llSrz.jpg)) contains the same typo. The Dominion is referred to as being in the Delta quadrant, not the Gamma

Comment: *How would we know if they had?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the end of DS9, the Founders sign an instrument of surrender known as the ['Treaty of Bajor'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Treaty_of_Bajor). A closer view of the prop shows that one of the key stipulations is that **all Founders (and their vassals) must leave the Alpha Quadrant immediately and remain in the Gamma Quadrant**.

This would obviously explain the conspicuous absence of any Founders in future episodes of Voyager or the subsequent theatrical films.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> All military forces of the Dominion, including Founder, Jem’Hadar,
>   Vorta, or other allies are to withdraw from the Alpha Quadrant
>   effective 26 hours following the general ceasefire order. No Dominion
>   military personnel, spacecraft, or materiel are to remain in the Alpha
>   Quadrant without the express written consent of the joint Alpha
>   Quadrant powers.

Comment: And no one had discovered the wormhole yet during _Enterprise_, so that explains their absence in that series.

Comment: It says "all _military_ forces", which doesn't preclude Founders per se to travel to the Alpha Quadrant though...

Comment: @mb21 - As the military leaders of the Dominion, I think you'd have a hard time arguing that any Founder could be described as non-military. My guess is that, erring on the side of caution, you'd simply bar their entire race access to the wormhole unless invited.

Comment: Is that... paper? In the 24th century?

Comment: Must be some special archival membrane or similar used for very important documents. Or a production error.

Comment: @JAB - What's wrong with paper? We see a number of printed baseball cards that have survived very nicely for more than 500 years, thank you; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kivas_Fajo

Comment: @Valorum There's a difference between antique collectibles and a contemporary government document. (Of course, it could be a plastic with lots of embedded security/identification features that just happens to look like 20th-century paper.)

Comment: @JAB - I choose to believe that it's just paper. Note that in both UK and US law, treaties have to be **physically signed** by the Head of State before they're considered to be enacted. There's no good reason why that shouldn't be the case in the future, even if they're largely a paperless society.

Comment: @Valorum - on the other hand, the Khitomer Accords (in DS9 too) are reinstated using a PADD

Comment: Because we have paper from 1,000 years ago, we know it can last 1,000 years. The same cannot be said in-universe for any of the Federation’s technology in Star Trek (as long as we ignore evidence gleaned from time travel).

Comment: @Edmund - Ah, but the original accords were signed.

Comment: The paper is cerimonial, the acutal document is several Gigaquads of law-speek, indecipherable to the average creature

Answer (score 1):

The Changelings return in *Star Trek: Discovery*, some 32 centuries later. They survive and cheat.

Comment: Welcome Sundhere. Could you provide some supporting in-universe reference for this as it's pretty bare at present. Also the 32 centuries idea, which season is that?

Comment: A link in the answer to [here](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-discovery-changeling-odo-ds9-season-4/) and pulling some quotes would be a decent way to flesh this out. And it's the 32nd century, about 800 years later, rather than 32 centuries later.