# Are the Cardassians (and Breen) required to withdraw from their homeworlds?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

Having just run across this answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121239/22680

where the wording of the Treaty of Bajor is quoted:

> **All military forces of the Dominion**, including Founder, Jem’Hadar, Vorta, **or other allies** are to withdraw from the Alpha Quadrant effective 26 hours following the general ceasefire order. No Dominion military personnel, spacecraft, or materiel are to remain in the Alpha Quadrant without the express written consent of the joint Alpha Quadrant powers.

I have to wonder:

- Cardassia is a member of the Dominion, and their military is most definitively a *"military force of the Dominion"*. Yes, they turned against the Dominion during the final battle, but this only means the Guls doing so are guilty of mutiny and/or treason. However, by all legal means, they are members of the Dominion.
- Breen is *not* a member of the Dominion (although you can occasionally find the claim that they let themselves "be annexed" by the Dominion). They nevertheless, very clearly qualifiy as "other allies" according to their actions as Dominion ally (delivering energy-damping weapons, attacking Earth, attacking Starfleet ships, patrolling Cardassia, etc.).
- Romulans *used to be* Dominion allies, but officially renounced Dominion membership and subsequently declared war on the Dominion after Sisko's ruse. Thus, Romulans are "safe".

Following the above wording, both Cardassian and Breen military forces would need to leave the alpha quadrant (nothing is said about civilians, though).

Thus, did these two parties get said "express written consent"? Seeing how the Romulans (who are a member of the Joint Powers) are neighbours to the Breen, I cannot imagine they would agree to granting such written consent, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Maybe Cardassian and Breen forces are not forces “of” the Dominion, but forces who fought *with* the Dominion. The Prophets could probably tell us, given that they knew that (SPOILERS) Sisko was “of” Bajor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the Changelings (Founders) appear outside of Star Trek: Deep Space 9?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121234/do-the-changelings-founders-appear-outside-of-star-trek-deep-space-9)

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe since the quote in my answer below (which explicitly answers this question) also appears in my answer to the [linked question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121239/22680).

Comment: @Valorum: Hmm... the text in the image indeed mentions borders , sovereignty and ownership of territories... but it says nothing about restoring military forces. I mean, try to look at it from a Romulan point of view: It _very clearly_ says the military must go. Verbatim. Generosity and honesty are not well-known Romulan virtues, but enforcing contracts to the letter (while advantageous) is certainly one. Giving back "sovereignty and ownership" of territories but without allowing military, only so you can conquer them in 2-3 years, does that not look **exactly** like a good Romulan plan?

Comment: This is the relevant bit "*All Alpha Quadrant territories presently under Dominion control, whether seized by force **or by treaty**, are to be returned to the control of the Alpha Quadrant powers.*". That almost certainly includes ceding *local* defence forces back to the control of local governments. Cardassians included.

Comment: Not sure. The prop's image is kinda hard to read, but for what it's worth I can indeed decipher "Cardassian Union" (incorrectly) among the joint alpha quadrant powers. No mention of the Breen, but they qualify as "other". Funnily, it's also about ending hostilities in the delta quadrant, not gamma. While I agree that ceding a planet's local defence is probably within "are to be returned", the wording ("Alpha Quadrant Powers") suggests that the previously named would hold power (Breen not being mentioned as "Alpha Power"). So basically...a kind of custodianship? Also, even if planetary defenses

Comment: are being handed back to the civilian leaders (which is kinda reasonable), does that imply that you are allowed to keep a military fleet of several hundred armed ships, with ten thousands of soldiers while the treaty explicitly says "military must go"? I am not sure. Would be nice to know -- since all the key points such as cessation of hostilities etc. are mere "additional conditions" -- what the actual conditions are, as well.

Comment: @damon - The Dominion's military needs to go, not the ships that were part of the normal Alpha Quadrant military. Think of this as the "reset button". The goal is to renormalise power in the quadrant, not to set the losers up for future invasions.

Answer (score 8):

You need to look a little further [down the page](https://p1.liveauctioneers.com/1034/74753/38846910_2_x.jpg)

> All Alpha Quadrant territories presently under Dominion control,
>   whether seized by force or by treaty, are to be returned to the
>   control of the Alpha Quadrant powers.
>
> All borders, sovereignty, and ownership of affected territories are to
>   revert to their status as of stardate 50564.0.

So it's pretty clear that the intention is to simply '*reset the clock*', setting everything back to where it was before the Dominion attacked the Alpha Quadrant.

---