# What does the Changeling's signature say on the 'Treaty of Bajor'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121239/3823) provides a screen capture of the Treaty of Bajor, ending the Dominion War, as well as showing a Founder signing it.

Of course, we can assume that the representatives of the Federation, Romulus, Klingon Empire, and Bajor all signed their name, which is customary (at least for us).

But changelings lack names (except Odo).   So what exactly does the Changeling's signature say?

Comment: What I find interesting is that, despite being party to the treaty and arguably the most affected by it, there's no Cardassian delegate's signature. Granted that it couldn't be Damar or anyone else the audience has heard of, but still.

Comment: @Cadence - Cardassia is, at this point in the proceedings, a member of the Dominion and hence bound by their signature.

Comment: @Valorum in which case they'd have to move to the Gamma Quadrant, per the terms of the treaty

Comment: @OrangeDog - Ah, but it also says that "*The Cardassian government would be returned to the control of the Detapa Council.*" as of the ratification of the treaty and that "*The Dominion will end its occupation of the Cardassian Union, reestablishing the Cardassian Union as a free and independent state.*", again, as of the ratification of the treaty (and, presumably therefore, not before).

Answer (score 6):

The only signature that's readable in English is Admiral Ross'. The others are written in different languages, although the Founders' signature also appears to be in English (or possibly letters that merely happen to look like English letters).

If I had to guess, it's

> "Fr D"

Which is possibly an abbreviation of "**F**ounde**r** of the **D**ominion" (noting that the text directly above where she's signed says "For the FOUNDERS OF THE DOMINION")

[image]

Comment: Maybe her name is secretly Fred

Comment: It looks like whoever wrote the Federation signature also wrote the Founders signature, which is a little disappointing from a production standpoint.

Comment: @BurhanAli - The prop is barely visible in the show. You should consider yourself lucky that it's got actual words on it at all